# How to do a server side filter in ag-grid floating filter

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, angular8

I am using Ag-grid free edition in which i have loaded the datas from server.I have set the floatingFilter option as true which filters the datas available.But i would like to filter the data from server side (Global filter for each column).

I have tried the below code for every input from the user storing it the store and making a server call and getting the response.

But what happens is

- this.loadData() throws an error 'this.loadData() is not a function'
- If the input is cleared i am trying to clear the store but couldn't
  make it.

```
this.columnDefs = [
      { headerName: 'ID', width: 100, valueGetter: (args) => this.getIdValue(args) },
      {
        headerName: 'Action',
        field: 'action',
        filterParams: {
          filterOptions: ['contains'],
          textCustomComparator: function(filter, value, filterText) {
            const filteredText = filterText.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + filterText.slice(1);
            if (filteredText) {
              store.dispatch(new ListStoreActions.ActionFilter(filteredText));
              store.dispatch(new ListStoreActions.SetCurrentPage());
              this.loadData(); //throwing error since it is called from constructor
            } else {
              console.log('else block got called');
              store.dispatch(new ListStoreActions.RemoveActionFilter());
            }
          },
        },
        debounceMs: 2000,
        suppressMenu: true,
        floatingFilterComponentParams: { suppressFilterButton: true }
      },
      { headerName: 'Collection', field: 'collectionName'},
      { headerName: 'Date', field: 'date'},
      { headerName: 'End Point', field: 'endpoint'},
      { headerName: 'IP', field: 'ipAddress' },
      { headerName: 'Method', field: 'method' },
      { headerName: 'Status Code', field: 'statusCode' },
    ];
```

I am calling the above in the constructor

I would like to know whether the approach i have done is correct or is there any better solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

> this.loadData() throws an error 'this.loadData() is not a function'

I think this issue is related to scoping inside `textCustomComparator` function. Change your function declaration to `Arrow function` syntax like below.

```
      textCustomComparator: (filter, value, filterText) => {
        const filteredText = filterText.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + filterText.slice(1);
        if (filteredText) {
          store.dispatch(new ListStoreActions.ActionFilter(filteredText));
          store.dispatch(new ListStoreActions.SetCurrentPage());
          this.loadData(); //throwing error since it is called from constructor
        } else {
          console.log('else block got called');
          store.dispatch(new ListStoreActions.RemoveActionFilter());
        }
      }
```

More reference on [`Arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)